# Laptop boots to Acer logo and goes off, boots to logo again

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, black-screen-of-death

I've been experiencing the black screen of death with cursor everytime i turn on my laptop since yesterday. I was unable to boot to safe mode also. I tried so many solutions but to no avail. 
However, i found a solution that i thought should work. It instructed me to go to command prompt in windows startup, copy the directories of c:\ and overwrite them on the directories of c:\windows\system32\config\RegBack.

After doing this windows 10 started performing automatic repair every time i turn the laptop on and would go next to the automatic repair screen. 
An article suggested i go to command prompt from advanced options, type bcdedit and change device partition from \Device\HarddiskVolume2 to c in order to solve the 'Automatic Repair' problem. I did that but didn't solve my problem. So i went ahead of myself, i changed Windows Boot Loader path from windows\system32\winload.efi to windows\system32\winload.exe. Now everytime i turn on the laptop, it just boots to the Acer logo, goes off, boots to the logo again, goes off repeatedly.

Am i screwed?

Comment: "Am i screwed?" - No. You can fix boot but eventually you have lost some software installations (when copying RegBack).

Comment: @snayob How do i fix the boot?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do to fix boot is:

```
bcdboot c:\windows /s Z: /f UEFI
```

where c: is Windows drive(change drive_letter if needed), Z: is EFI System partition.

Hint: Use diskpart.exe to map EFI System partition to Z:

Then try to boot to safe mode.

If above suggestion does not help you have to eventually make a clean installation of Windows 10.

Please note: Always create a full image of your Windows installation on external media so you can recover after 10-15 minutes in case of problems. Update this image say monthly so you have a recent image.

Note 2: Never mess up with "Registry" if you don't understand what you are doing!
In "Registry" are stored all the settings for your hardware and software which are crucial for proper operation of Windows and all installed programs.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did the fix boot and the boot files were created successfully but the situation stayed the same. Seems i'll back up my HDD just as @Darksoulpk68 suggested and perform a clean windows installation.

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if I'm wrong but you look like you understand IT Stuff, so I won't write a big procedure on how to, but feel free to ask me if you need so.

---

If you don't mind about your data you can go the easy way and simply reinstall Windows...

If you do mind about your data but still would like a fresh new installation of Windows then you could use another computer:

> - Unplug your HDD and plug it into another PC as Additionnal drive
> - start PC on the right HDD that does not crash
> - Explore your HDD and copy stuff you dont want to lose
> - Shut down PC
> - Put HDD in old PC
> - Reinstall Windows

Yet I'm not quite helping on how this happened.
But this could be a simple solution.

You could also try a fresh install with Partition Recovery, see if you can find back some files.

Also, you could use snayob's answer, which could work too.

> bcdboot C:\windows /s Z: /f UEFI
>   Where C: is Windows drive(change drive_letter if needed), Z: is EFI System partition.
>   Hint: Use diskpart.exe to map EFI System partition to Z: